# Dúvida sobre performance no uso do using statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Qual das duas formas de verificar se um registro de tal TIPO já foi cadastrado é mais performático? Há diferenças, erros? Quais as implicações? O bloco `using` libera apenas os recursos da conexão ou todos os objetos criados em seu escopo? A memória utilizada pelo `using` tem prioridade no GC? Há outra forma melhor de fazer tal verificação?

Bloco 1

```
int valorDoTipo = 5;
Tipo tipo;

using (Contexto contexto = new Contexto())
{
    tipo = contexto.Tipo.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ValorDoTipo == valorDoTipo);
}

if (tipo != null)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Bloco 2

```
using (Contexto contexto = new Contexto())
{
    int valorDoTipo = 5;
    Tipo tipo;        
    tipo = contexto.Tipo.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ValorDoTipo == valorDoTipo);
    if (tipo != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: O final (as 4 linhas do `if`) do seu código pode ser escrito como `return tipo != null;`

Comment: é, a expressão booleana direto, tão simples... nunca pensei nisso, seria falta de experiência?

Comment: Provavelmente, por isso você estamos todos aqui, aprendendo com a experiência dos outros. Inclusive os menos experientes ajudam os mais experientes, afinal, cada uma com a sua experiência.

Comment: @CaiqueC. o entity framework é muito legal e tem tanta coisa que até hoje vivo aprendendo, o mais importante é isso e vamos dizer não é falta de experiência, é um aprendizando para sempre ... parabéns!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem soluções melhores e mais performáticas do que você me passou na sua pergunta, uma delas logo abaixo:

***Explicação:*** Como você quer um retorno `(true ou false)` seria a melhor forma essa ai, não precisa retorna um `Tipo` como os da pergunta.

```
bool retorno = false;
using (Contexto contexto = new Contexto())
{                 
    retorno = contexto.Tipo.Any(t => t.ValorDoTipo == 5);    
}
return retorno;
```

ou

```
bool retorno = false;
using (Contexto contexto = new Contexto())
{                 
    retorno = contexto.Tipo.AsNoTracking().Any(t => t.ValorDoTipo == 5);    
}
return retorno;
```

O `AsNoTracking()`, significa que ele vai executar um comando SQL no seu banco e não vai anexar ao seu contexto, ou seja, aumenta a performance do comando. Tal comando é muito utilizado em pesquisas, aonde o intuito é só trazer informações (*ReadOnly*).

Obs: São dois iguais `(==)` na comparação dado visto na tag da pergunta [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Referências:

- [DbExtensions.AsNoTracking Method (IQueryable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)
- [Diferença de AsNoTracking e AutoDetectChanges no Entity Framework](http://www.bufaloinfo.com.br/ExibeNoticias.aspx?entryid=4056709612566575248)
- [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 11: Load and AsNoTracking](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/05/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-11-load-and-asnotracking.aspx)

Comment: Pode me dar mais informações sobre o método AsNoTracking()?

Comment: @CaiqueC. editei a questão, geralmente a gente usa isso para otimizar a pesquisa e não deixa-la em cache! não tem necessidade no seu cenário.

Comment: Entendi, mas aqui não estou tendo acesso a este método. Seria a versão do EF? (não sei qual estou usando, mas meu VS é 2010)

Comment: Dá pra fazer mais curto ainda: `return contexto.Tipo.AsNoTracking().Any(t => t.ValorDoTipo == 5);`

Comment: @CaiqueC. o que você não encontrou? qual método?

Comment: AsNoTracking().

Comment: @CaiqueC. utilize sem, então, resolve também como está agora a minha edição da questão!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pode ser, mas, é melhor sempre colocar o `return` na última linha é boa prática !!!

Comment: @HarryPotter ok, vou utilizar sem, mas... sabe me dizer o porquê de eu não ter acesso ao método? Seria a versão do EF, .Net? E utilizando sem, eu estarei deixando os dados em cache?

Comment: @CaiqueC. era pra ter, é dificil eu prever o que ta na sua tela, peço até desculpas, sobre o cache nesse caso pode ficar sem porque ele retorna um tipo primitivo simples não vai ter tanta diferenças, mas, se fizer em pesquisas com massa de dados e forem tipados faz uma grande diferença!

Comment: @HarryPotter Ok, sem problemas. Mesmo o sistema pedindo para evitar coisas do tipo, obrigado.

Comment: @CaiqueC. tente assim: talvez pela versão do EF funcione: `contexto.Tipo.Where(t => t.ValorDoTipo == 5).AsNoTracking().Any();` só para tirar a prova eu acho que você ta mexendo com a 4.

Comment: @HarryPotter não funcionou... vou pesquisar um pouco, estágio é pra isso né rs